# How to hide a class inside of a static library in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, static-libraries

I want to only have 2 extern C functions, which are how to interact with the API.  Then inside the static .lib I want to have my class that does all the work.  But it shouldnt be visible to the outside.

I can do it with just pure C functions by declaring them static inside a compilation unit, but how do I do it with a class ?

Comment: Unless they have the exact class definition there isn't much they can do with it. Probably not worth the time to even worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question well:

- you want to create a static library presenting only two functions to the outside world
- but the internals of this library should be based on a class you want to hide from outside world.
- you know how to do hiding internals in classic c (i.e. using auxiliary static functions and static variables) but you don't see how to do with classes

If this is the case,  the trick is simply to use an **unamed namespace**:

In your library source you would have something like this:

```
namespace {  // anonymous
    class U {   // class visible only to the library
    public: 
        int y;  
        U() :y(0) { cout << "U\n"; } 
        void mrun() { y++; } 
    };
}

void f() {
    U x; 
    ...
}
```

You may then use your library from outsilde world:

```
extern void f();   // declare the function (in a header) 
f();               // invoke the function
```

Even if the auxiliary class would be declared in the outside world:

```
class U { public: int y;  U(); void mrun(); };
```

It would not be able to used and linking errors would be generated if it would be tempted to use U.  This is because unnamed namespaces are unique to each compilation unit.

If you use the same kind of solution but without the anonymous namespace, the auxiliary class would be visible and the link would succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could mirror the class's API using C functions a bit like this:

```
class Cpp
{
    int i = 0;

public:

    int get_i() { return i; }
    void set_i(int i) { this->i = i; }
};

// C code has a void* as a handle to access
// the correct instance of CPP
extern "C" void* new_Cpp()
{
    return new Cpp;
}

extern "C" void delete_Cpp(void* cpp)
{
    delete reinterpret_cast<Cpp*>(cpp);
}

extern "C" int Cpp_get_i(void* cpp)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<Cpp*>(cpp)->get_i();
}

extern "C" void Cpp_set_i(void* cpp, int i)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<Cpp*>(cpp)->set_i(i);
}
```